# Angular 6 Share module not work

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am Create an angular 6 application, i have need a share header for any page or some pages, i include this but not working. What's I am wrong ?. get DEMO https://angualr-6-shared-module-work.stackblitz.io error show when I am routing the login url ** and error here** "

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-primery-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-primery-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-primery-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<app-primery-header></app-primery-header>
```

***here my code: in App Module***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

// routing 
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Login Module Is**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { PrimeryHeaderModule } from '../share';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, LoginRoutingModule,PrimeryHeaderModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

**Router module is**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export **`HeaderComponent`** in **HeaderModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  exports: [HeaderComponent]
})
```

**[WORKING STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pflu86?file=src/app/share/header/header.module.ts)**

Comment: Yea Thank You Bro.