# How to import separate component in lazy loading module which is defined in app module?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular7

Unable to load separate component in Angular 7 lazy load. If I load entire modules related to that component in one component, that's working fine. When I'm loading component only on another component, it's showing error.. nothing will load on the website...

Comment: Create a shared module and import in both condition.

Comment: how to create a shared module ?
Could you please elaborate this ??

Comment: A really Good article on medium https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-4-shared-modules-18ac50f24852

Comment: same way we have integrated shared module with different name. But it work works for me.

Comment: Can you share the minimum code on stackbliz?

Comment: Hi @BALAJIR you can follow this URL :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270582/angular-6-share-module-not-work/50270627#50270627